# Is there a command or program can add line number to display by pipe?

Tags: shell, grep, vim, pipe

I always need to find some key words in thousands of feedback and locate it in which line. I used to redirect feedback to a file, and open file wiith vim, and execute vim command `:set nu` to do this. But it is pretty inconvenient and cause some unnecessary disk IO.
So I wonder if there is a command can achive below results:

```
$ sudo my-command | line-number-command | grep 'foo\|bar'
114  bla bla bla foo
514  bla bar bla bla
810  foo bla bla bla
1919 bla bla bar bla
```

Comment: Well there's `nl` - but `grep` itself has a `-n` option for line numbering

Comment: Honest question - Why put that in a comment rather than as an answer?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds because the question was obviously just going to get downvoted and closed since the OP could've answered it themselves with a glance at the grep man page or looking at past questions here or just a quick google and sometimes when you answer a question like that your answer also gets downvoted for encouraging such questions. So if you feel like throwing the OP a bone then doing so in a comment is reasonable.

Comment: Makes sense - Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo my-command | cat -n | grep 'foo\|bar'`

Or, as steeldriver mentioned in the comments, `nl` is probably a better answer.

Comment: ```nl``` is exactly what I want! Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Or ask `grep` to output line number.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, when you only need to number the lines which match a pattern, you don't need an additional command: it's simpler and much more efficient to simply use the `-n` option of `grep`:

```
$ sudo my-command | grep -n 'foo\|bar'
114:  bla bla bla foo
514:  bla bar bla bla
810:  foo bla bla bla
1919: bla bla bar bla
```

It would be a huge waste of ressources to prefix *all* lines of the input file with numbers (and in the process create an additional intermediate file/pipe), if you only want to print a small percentage of them.

(BTW, you can also use `grep -n $`  to number *all* lines! This may be less efficient than `nl`, but not that much, and since we are more likely to forget `nl` than to forget `grep`, it might be easier to remember.)